# Import bacpac file to existing WASD on Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have followed the steps mentioned on [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh335292.aspx) and i have created new DB successfully on azure portal. However i would like to know how can i import that on existing database using .bacpac file?

Answer (score 2):

Currently the given answer won't work because as of now, the interface of the Azure portal has changed significantly. You won't find the import button that easily!
Supposing that you have clicked SQL databases from the navigation panel, then at the bottom, click "New". Then you will find Import button. The rest is easy.
It took me around 2 hours to figure out what Microsoft wrote in their [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/hh335292.aspx) and what I am visualizing in their portal! It doesn't match and Microsoft forgot to update their documentations!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import the bacpac file through the Windows Azure portal you'll need to go to **SQL Databases** and press the **Import** button. You will be able to choose a bacpac from one of your storage accounts (you can upload bacpac files to your storage account with a free tool like [CloudXplorer](http://clumsyleaf.com/products/cloudxplorer)).

[image]

**Note:** The import process does not allow you to import into an existing database. You'll get the option to create a new database.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have already done with creating new DB using backpac file however i was looking to import same on existing one! It seems that there is no restore like option for WASD, right?

Comment: As described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362015(v=vs.100).aspx), there should be some scenarios where you can import objects in an existing database, but you'll need to use the latest version of the [SQL Server Data Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027).